# Get error to call HandshakeException:unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:363))

Tags: flutter

I get this error when i call api with get and post Method using `http` or `dio`.
How can i resolve this error.
[image]

This is my api calling code and below is console showing error
[image: This is error image which is console show]

Comment: Seems your url is wrong, Please check it in postman

Comment: it would be good it you share code instead of image in your question

Comment: In postman it's working well.
and also working well in chrome